# Why are my DbContext creating proxies for my objects in runtime but not in the unit tests?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have an application built with Entity Framework 4.0 and .NET 4.5. As I'm using the default code generation item, it's generating a `DbContext` and `POCOs` for tables.

When I'm at runtime, whenever I execute a query, the returning objects are always of dynamically generated proxy types that inherit from the original types. E.g, if I have a `Person` type, the queries will always return a `Person_48573435` (it's not the exact name) that inherits from `Person`.

However, in my unit tests, that just doesn't happen, which is causing some behaviours to differ from on context to the other.

the only difference in the instantiation of the `DbContext` is that, in the unit tests, I'm explicitly passing in the connection string and at runtime it's taken from the `web.config` file. By the way, I had to alter the TT so I could introduce a constructor that receives the connection string. Not sure why Microsoft removed this constructor as it was present in the ObjectContext TT. Anyway, everything works fine except for this proxy thing.

The question is? What controls the way the query returning objects are instantiated? What could I have done to influence this behavior?

Comment: Check what `ctx.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled` is set to in your tests.

Comment: @Pawel, thanks for your reply. I didn't even know of this property but it's true in both cases =/

Comment: Assuming that you are using the same entities proxies should be created as in your main project. I don't think it should matter but you can try adding the config file to your test suite and use the same ctor you use in your product - just to check if you get the proxies or not. Re ctor: you don't have to modify T4 templates to have the additional ctor. The generated DbContext derived class is partial so you can just another part of this class in your project that would contain this ctor.